# Bottom scrollBar in CardScrollView

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, cardscrollview

I have a question about CardScrollView. Since each item on the CardScrollView takes up the full card, I would like to have the scrollbar showing at the bottom of the Card to indicate there are other items within this CardScrollView just like the the menu in glass.

I tired enabling setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled and setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnable nut nothing happen. I was also looking into setShowCardSheenEnabled but there is no such method for CardScrollView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>`CardScrollView` does not yet support this. Please follow the feature request for this, [issue 256](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=256), in our issue tracker so that you can be updated as the GDK evolves.</strike>

**UPDATE:** This is now supported by calling `setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true)` on the `CardScrollView`.

Comment: Will do! Thanks Tony!